# RDCOMClient remove auto filter

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I have opened a workbook with RDCOMClient and would like to remove the auto filter on a certain sheet:

```
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE 
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open('file.xlsx')

## sheet with data filters
sheet <- xlWbk$Worksheets('Sheet1')
```

I've tried a couple things like:

```
sheet$AutoFilter()[['Value']] = FALSE
```

and

```
sheet$AutoFilter()$Filter = FALSE
```

But haven't been able to quite turn disable the data filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick. Looked up the VBA Code and converted it. Should be useful in the future.

```
sheet[["AutofilterMode"]] <- F
```

Comment: can you explain 'Looked up the VBA Code and converted it'?

Comment: Yes, I checked how to do it in VBA and then tried to use the syntax in R. See here: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/turn-autofilter-on-off/